# How to add circles around markers on Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

This is a code that I use to display markers on several places in google maps.
I want to make an addition to this and add a 5km circle around the markers.

[image]

I tried with adding this block of code without luck:

```
var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
center:position, 
radius: radius, 
fillColor: "#0000FF", 
fillOpacity: 0.1, 
map: map, 
strokeColor: "#FFFFFF", 
strokeOpacity: 0.1, 
strokeWeight: 2 
});
```

this is the full code below, and here is a jsfiddle for reference

```
var center = "Vilnius, Lithuania";
var locations = [
  ['Tuskulėnų g. 20, Vilnius 09211, Lithuania', "some info"],
  ['Stumbrų g. 21, Vilnius 08101, Lithuania', "more information"],
  ['Kalvarijų g. 55, Vilnius 09317, Lithuania', "blah, blah"],
  ['Birželio 23-iosios g. 6, Vilnius 03204, Lithuania', "other information"],
  ['Teatro g. 6, Vilnius 03107, Lithuania', "to be determined"]
];


var geocoder;
var map;
var infoWin = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
  // center and zoom map on "center" address
  geocoder.geocode({
    address: center
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.bounds);
    } else {
      alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
  });
  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    codeAddress(locations[i], i);
  }

}

function codeAddress(location, i) {
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': location[0]
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        title: "marker " + i,
        position: results[0].geometry.location
      });
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(evt) {
        infoWin.setContent(location[0] + "<br>" + location[1]);
        infoWin.open(map, this);
      })


//i added this block
var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
center:position, 
radius: radius, 
fillColor: "#0000FF", 
fillOpacity: 0.1, 
map: map, 
strokeColor: "#FFFFFF", 
strokeOpacity: 0.1, 
strokeWeight: 2 
});
//end of block addition

    } else {
      alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

**Update**

this is what I get from the console

```
radius is not defined
```

Comment: I don't see any attempt to add the circle in the posted code (or a fiddle for that matter).  What did you try that didn't work?

Comment: @geocodezip hi there, I added the block of code before the last `}else{` so as to be in the loop of the `i`

Comment: Still don't see it in the posted code.  Just adding it and adjusting the variables appropriately works for me, are you getting javascript errors (like `position` is not definded, `radius` is not defined)?

Comment: @geocodezip I have updated my question, and added what I get back from the console. `radius is not defined`

Comment: Did you try defining the radius?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have just to define `radius` and `position` variable, e.g :

```
var radius = 1000;
var position = marker.getPosition();
```

And for tha zoom you can use `map.setZoom();`, add it after `setCenter` for example :

```
map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
map.setZoom(5);
```

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4mtyu/1007/)**.

---

**code snippet:**

```js
var center = "Vilnius, Lithuania";
var locations = [
  ['Tuskulėnų g. 20, Vilnius 09211, Lithuania', "some info"],
  ['Stumbrų g. 21, Vilnius 08101, Lithuania', "more information"],
  ['Kalvarijų g. 55, Vilnius 09317, Lithuania', "blah, blah"],
  ['Birželio 23-iosios g. 6, Vilnius 03204, Lithuania', "other information"],
  ['Teatro g. 6, Vilnius 03107, Lithuania', "to be determined"]
];


var geocoder;
var map;
var infoWin = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

function codeAddress(location, i) {
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': location[0]
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      map.setZoom(5);

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        title: "marker " + i,
        position: results[0].geometry.location
      });
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(evt) {
        infoWin.setContent(location[0] + "<br>" + location[1]);
        infoWin.open(map, this);
      })

      var radius = 1000;
      var position = marker.getPosition();

      var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: position,
        radius: radius,
        fillColor: "#0000FF",
        fillOpacity: 0.1,
        map: map,
        strokeColor: "#FFFFFF",
        strokeOpacity: 0.1,
        strokeWeight: 2
      });

    } else {
      alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", function() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
  // center and zoom map on "center" address
  geocoder.geocode({
    address: center
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
        map.setZoom(map.getZoom() + 3);
      });
      map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.bounds);

    } else {
      alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    codeAddress(locations[i], i);
  }
});
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: hey really thank you for this, but i want to make use of the position name, and not latlng. And to have a circle around all the markers, not a generic one...

Comment: You're welcome, check my updated answer (also fiddle updated).

Comment: I accepted your answer, thank you very much, it was really helpful. In line 22, just below `map:map` I added a `zoom:5` without luck

Comment: You're welcome, normally you should add it in `map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {zoom: 20});`.

Comment: Hi, can you help me with the zoom feature?

Comment: Hey can you help me with the zoom please ?